# Using special character " and ` in send command in expect script

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, expect

I am trying to execute a command in Linux servers to fetch which all servers requires root password reset as there are multiple servers I am using an expect script to automate it , my command contains special characters like double quotes and grave accent `` ` `` . so on execution it give extra characters after double quotes as an error .

```
send " chage -l root | grep -i "Password expires" | if [[ `awk -F : '{print $2}' ` = "never" ]] ; then echo "password needs to be changed " ;else echo "skipping reset " ; fi;\r"
```

I tried using `\` with double quotes but the error remains same

Comment: `\`` is not the problem, the problem is `$2` in the awk script.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a string with no interpolation in [Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk/about/language.html) (the language expect uses), and it does not have have `{}` chars or variables you want to expand, then enclose it in `{}`. Eg:

```
send { chage -l root | grep -i "Password expires" | if [[ `awk -F : '{print $2}' ` = "never" ]] ; then echo "password needs to be changed " ;else echo "skipping reset " ; fi;}
send \r
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put back-slashes? On all quotes or only on the inner ones like this?

```
send " chage -l root | grep -i \"Password expires\" | if [[ `awk -F : '{print \$2}' ` = \"never\" ]] ; then echo \"password needs to be changed \" ;else echo \"skipping reset \" ; fi;\r"
```

And yes, you need to `\` a `$` character also, because this string will be passed to the command and you don't need `bash` to resolve it too early.